Not Receiving Email Confirmation for Proposal Creation on Area 51
I'm experiencing an issue where I'm not receiving the email confirmation required to create a proposal on Area 51.
The goal is a register a Stack Exchange site for an open source community.
This is the URL I am using: https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/create?category=technology
I have tried using several emails and browsers.


If this is a silent discontinuation of Area 51 by Stack Exchange to switch focus over to corporate clients with closed spaces it would be nice to know what alternatives people are using.

Check your spam folder, the verification email might have been marked spam by some filter you have in place.

@ShadowWizard This is a repost of a deleted question in which OP specified that they'd checked their spam folder. I've been able to recreate the issue and have not received the email in my inbox or spam folder either.

Attempts to Resolve:
Checked spam/junk folders.
Ensured that my email address is correct.
Tried using different email addresses.
Tried using different browsers (Safari, Firefox).
Tried resending the confirmation email multiple times.
Reloaded the page after each attempt.
Despite these steps, the confirmation email has not been received. This issue persists across multiple email addresses and browsers.

tl dr: The email is not in my spam folder.

OK, thanks. Wonder if anyone does get it still, and hope SE will fix it soon anyway.

Anyway you better get rid of the last paragraph and replace it with what you said in comments, i.e. what you checked and tried already. I considered editing it myself but better coming from you. Cheers!
